# Pandas Dataframe Assert Equals with nan

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am looking to assert that two dataframes are the same.  When use df1 == df2 with np.nan's, the test does not pass, while when I use pd.testing.assert_frame_equal works.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'A': [1, 2], 'B': [np.nan, np.nan]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

# First Option
print((df1 == df2).all().all())

# First option Issues
print((df1 == df2))

# Second Option passes
print(pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1, df2) is None)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `nan` doesn't equal `nan` by definition.

Comment: it's very philosophical: two nans are never the same

Comment: OK.  So,  the second method is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NaN`s are not equal to themselves.

```
float('nan') == float('nan')
# False
```

Which makes it impossible to use only `(df1 == df2).all().all()`.

You would also need to check the `NaN` status:

```
(df1.eq(df2)|df1.isna()).all().all()
# True
```

[`assert_frame_equal`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal.html) handles NaN equality.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use [`DataFrame.equals()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html#pandas-dataframe-equals). `NaN`s in the same location are considered equal.

```py
print(df1.equals(df2))
```

Prints:

```
True
```